# WYSIHTML5 - very slow when creating multiple instances

Tags: jquery, performance, wysiwyg, wysihtml5

I'm using [WYSIHTML5](https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5) to convert a textarea into an editor. The editor is quite simple. It provides just basic functionality like bold/underline/italic and inserting custom varaibales.

Everthing works fine when I load only one instance of WYSIHTML5, but when I display like 5 or 10 in a listing, it freezes the whole browser for like 1 to 2 seconds.

I guess I found the reason why it takes so long. When I initiate the editor, it creates an iframe, which is the actual editor. This is the part where it hangs.

Is it possible to load a div instead of an iframe?
I know there is a security reason why the dev team of WYSIHTML5 took iframes, but anyway it is quite slow with iframes.

Comment: why not use something like ckeditor - very easy to plugin, configure and use and and most of the large content management systems use it

Comment: @Pete ckeditor is quite heavy for the purpose. WYSIHTML5 is lightweight and it has all options I need, but becomes so laggy because of the iframe creation.

Comment: ah ok, was just an different option if you can't get WYSIHTML5 to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the WYSIHTML5 input box is produced but providing you include all the required JS and CSS files on the destination page, is there any reason why you can't retrieve all the content using ajax or php-include?

E.g.

```
<?php include("source/of/the/editor.html");?>
```

or

```
 $.ajax({   
    type:"GET",
    url: "source/of/the/editor.html",
    data: "",
    success: function(data){
       $('.requiredDIVs').html(data);
    }
 });
```

Comment: That is exactly what I do. The problem happens when I apply `new wysihtml5.Editor(...)`. It creates an iframe for every textarea which is loading the browsers.

Comment: hmm ok looking at the source JS file of the plugin, it looks heavily set into using an iFrame. You could quite possibly edit the plugin yourself to use a div instead (but this would be very time consuming). As @Pete suggested `ckeditor` does have an option to use a div instead of an iFrame, and you could cut it down a fair bit so it wasn't so heavy. Sorry I can't help any further